# What am I missing? -SETS BASIC-

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A:(1,2,3,4,5) , B:(3,4,5,7), C:(2,4,6,8)  then (A∩C)-B ?

I thought

A∩C:(2,4)

(A∩C)-B then must be (2,4)-(3,4,5,7)=(2)

What am I missing here?

While writing difference set shouldn't we keep the different elements of the first set?

Comment: Why do you think this is wrong?

Comment: Because in a multiple choice exam they marked this as wrong.

Comment: I think it’s the right answer.

Comment: Thanks for checking

Comment: Assuming that you mean that $A=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and so on, what you have is right: $$(\{1,2,3,4,5\}\cap\{2,4,6,8\})\setminus\{3,4,5,7\}=\{2,4\}\setminus\{3,4,5,7\}=\{2\}\;.$$